# Тайм-аут подключения к контейнеру с mysql из go

Tags: mysql, golang, docker

Установил Docker Desktop for MacOS.
Запустил контейнер с mysql:`docker run --name mysqlserver -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -d mysql:latest`.
Docker ps выдает PORTS 3306/tcp, 33060/tcp.
`docker inspect mysqlserver | grep IPAddr` выдает `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"`.
Подключаюсь к mysql из golang `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:pass@tcp(172.17.0.2:3306)/employeedb")`
Получаю: `dial tcp 172.17.0.2:3306: connect: operation timed out`
Доступ к базе нужен только локальный. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

172.17.0.2 - это адрес внутри контейнера. С хост машины доступа нет. Вам нужно пробросить порт с хост машины в контейнер `-p 3306:3306`, либо  `--network host`(тут все порти внутри контейнера доступны на хост машине).

Comment: Перезапустил контейнер с пробросом портов docker run -p 3306:3306...
В go коннекторе изменил `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:pass@tcp(0.0.0.0:3306)/employeedb")` и все взлетело. Спасибо